# I think its Rotational Kinematics

Tags: geometry

I have a post two meters high with a diameter of ten (10) centermeters.  I rope is wrapped completely around the post (bottom to top).  The rope has a diameter of two (2) centermeters.  A crow picks up the end of the rope and flies continually around the post until all the rope is unwound.  The rope is kept taut.  How far does the crop fly?